# Can an incorrect VGA timing kill a modern LCD screen?

Tags: fpga, vga, artix-series-fpga

I'm going to play with an Artix-7 dev board with a VGA port (Nexys 4 DDR from Digilent) and I'm a beginner at this.

Assuming the pinout is correct, is it possible to destroy a (very) cheap modern LCD screen if I'm sending garbage/incorrect data to the VGA port?

Comment: Just a note... Decades back, I read up on an MCS-51 microcontroller intended for the CRT monitors of the data. It described using its timer inputs to measure HSYNC and VSYNC timings to determine if they represented a supported display mode and presumably to reject illegal timings. No idea if modern monitors do this function as a basic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely unlikely that an incorrect signal will damage the LCD.

Having said that, it still leaves an extremely small chance that it will damage it, but I would not worry about it.

Comment: So what you're saying it that it should be ok unless i stumble upon an 1-in-million-chance bug on the screen chipset ? something like that ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I ran into a situation once where a laptop VGA output worked with all other devices except one TFT display. And this TFT display VGA input worked with all other devices except the laptop. First time when those were plugged together, display power and backlight stayed on and undriven TFT panel just faded slowly to white. Display was dead and went on to service/warranty. When new/fixed display arrived, those two devices were tried again and same thing happened, it just died. When the next display arrived, it was not used with that laptop ever again.

Comment: Good enough for me. thank you :)

Comment: i'll just buy the smallest refurbished screen i can find and give it a try :)